# Redirecting to another page prevents functions from returning their values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, asynchronous

I have a Login page and if user logs in I want to redirect the user to another HTML page where I will list users tasks that I get from server.

The problem is:

Even though the functions I wrote works properly and backend API returns the values I want (I can see the value details on Console) when I  use redirect code `$window.location.href = '../Kullanici/userPanel.html` the page redirects immedietly after login and for some reason I can't use the values returned by functions after redirection. Not only that I can't see the details of the value returned on console log anymore.

And here is my code for it:

Controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window','$mdToast', 'userTaskList',
    function ($scope, $http, $window, $mdToast, userTaskList) {
        $scope.siteLogin = function () {

            var userName = $scope.panel.loginUserName;
            var password = $scope.panel.loginPassword;
            var loginMember = { //JSON data from login form
                K_ADI: $scope.panel.loginUserName,
                PAROLA: $scope.panel.loginPassword
            };
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:5169/api/Kullanicilar/KullaniciDogrula',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: loginMember

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                console.log("message sent", response);
                $scope.data = response.data.error.data;
                if ($scope.data === true) {//if username and password is correct

                    console.log("User exists");
                    userTaskList.showActiveTasks(userName)
                        .then(function (activeTaskResponse) {
                            var activeTasks = activeTaskResponse;
                            console.log("Active tasks (controller): ", activeTaskResponse);

                            userTaskList.showFinishedTasks(userName)
                                .then(function (finishedTaskResponse) {
                                    var finishedTasks = finishedTaskResponse;
                                    console.log("Finished tasks(controller): ", finishedTaskResponse);
                                    $scope.getMessage();
                                    $window.location.href = '../Kullanici/userPanel.html';
                                }, function (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                });

                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });

                }

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("Couldn't send", response);
            });
        }
```

**So what causes this problem and how can I fix it?**

Edit: I nested **.then** parts but it doesnt work properly and gives `This value was just evaluated now` warning. So I stil can't use data on the redirected HTML page.

I also removed the factory since it makes the code look really messy and its probably not the source of the problem.

Comment: This code needs deep edits! First thing first your login functionality should go to a service and in your controller you should only ask the service to do the dirty data job. Second, by using $window.location.href you are killing your app! if after successful login you want to be staying in your app, you'd need to use $location service.

Comment: @Babak sorry I'm a beginner in Angular. Can you please show it to me with code ? Atleast the $location service part because I didnt understand why its killing the app .

Comment: The question has been edited so many times that it is unclear what you are asking. Did you originally have the assignment of `$window.location.href` at the end of the `siteLogin` function? And now you have moved it to the bottom of the three nested `.then` methods? If that is the case, are you now getting the data from the server and then losing it when `$window.location.href` gets assigned?

Comment: @georgeawg I edited the code after Jacques Olivier's answer. Before that .thens wasn't nested and I couldn't even see the data on Console. So originally wherever I put $window.location.href it didn't solve my problem. Now after I edited code like Jacques Olivier's answer I can see that response returned from API in the console but I can't use nor see the data inside it. So I got close to solution but still having the main problem which is not being able to use the data on the HTML page that code redirects me.

Comment: @georgeawg I'll probably edit my question one last time to give mor clear details after trying your answer.

Comment: you are not getting values as these are returned after redirecting .

Comment: @AdeshKumar any idea on how can I fix it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577190/console-log-is-not-showing-correct-values

Comment: @AdeshKumar Sir I already implemented this into my Project. As I stated in my question problem occurs after redirecting. And I really can't see how an extra `.then ` would help me.

Comment: why are you using location.href, $location.path() is more comfortable for your use case

Comment: So are you trying to access the response items from the "../Kullanici/userPanel.html" page? sorry im just trying to understand what exactly you are still trying to do with the response.

Comment: @JacquesOlivier no `userPanel.html` is the HTML page where I will list the tasks that I get from API. There are two card components in the page for `activeTasks` and `finishedTasks` . But when I redirect to `userPanel.html` I can't use the values returend by the API. I can see some values returned in Console but can't click to see  details. Like I used to when I didn't use redirection

Comment: Yes, you wouldnt be able to access that info as the content, $scope variables and controller is no longer attached to the page... you have two choices here, 1st you could try load the data once you are on the userPage rather (this is what i would recommend), or you can store these values in $rootScope and then access them from the controller attached to userPanel (I would not recommend this approach as its not best practice)

Answer (score 6):

I would have nested the your two functions inside the first promise, then redirect once all of them are done. Something like

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window','$mdToast', 'userTaskList',
  function ($scope, $http, $window, $mdToast, userTaskList) {
    $scope.siteLogin = function () {

        var userName = $scope.panel.loginUserName;
        var password = $scope.panel.loginPassword;
        var loginMember = { //JSON data from login form
            K_ADI: $scope.panel.loginUserName,
            PAROLA: $scope.panel.loginPassword
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:5169/api/Kullanicilar/KullaniciDogrula',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: loginMember

        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            console.log("message sent", response);
            $scope.data = response.data.error.data;
            if ($scope.data === true) {//if username and password is correct

                console.log("User exists");
                userTaskList.showActiveTasks(userName)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        var activeTasks = res;
                        console.log("Active tasks (controller): ", res);

                        userTaskList.showFinishedTasks(userName)
                        .then(function (res) {
                            var finishedTasks = res;
                            console.log("Finished tasks(controller): ", res);
                            $scope.getMessage(); 
                            $window.location.href = '../Kullanici/userPanel.html';
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });

                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });

            } else { //if username or password is wrong
                $mdToast.show(
                    $mdToast.simple()
                        .textContent('Username or Password is wrong')
                        .position('right')
                        .hideDelay(3000)
                            );      
            } 
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Couldn't send", response);
        });          
     }
   }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks but even though I can see  the data in console now. It gives a warning saying : `Value below was evaluated just now`. Therefore I cannot use the data I get from API. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: try renaming one of the res parameters in the promise functions

Comment: did you change all instances of res in the showFinishedTasks method? that error is from angular thinking that you are trying to pass the res variable from the firsyt function into the second.

Comment: yes, unless I'm missing something... Here is the pastebin link for both factory and controller  : https://pastebin.com/Hm4ExKQ3

Also I read on other stack topics that same problem might be cause by timing.

Answer (score 6):

> Oh I injected [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api#-link-ngroute-ngroute-) to my AngularJS module but haven't use it yet.

Using `$window.location.href` kills the app and loads the other page, losing `$rootScope`, `$scope`, and all service data.

Re-factor your code to use a router and store the data in a service:

```
$routeProvider
 .when('/userPanel' , {
     templateUrl: 'partials/userPanel.html',
     controller: panelController
})
```

```
 panelService.set(data);
 $location.path("/userPanel.html");
```

OR use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the data:

```
 localStorage.setItem('panelData', JSON.stringify(data));
 $window.location.href = '../Kullanici/userPanel.html';
```

Data stored in a service will survive route changes (which destroy $scope). Data stored in `localStorage` will survive page changes (which destroy apps).

---

### The code can be simplified

This will solve the problem of having the page wait for the data before changing the route.

Since the `getMessages` function makes an HTTP request it needs to be modified to return a promise:

```
$scope.getMessages = getMessages;
function getMessages() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:5169/api/chat/chatCek'
    }).then(function successCallback(res) {
        console.log("Mesajlar", res);
        $scope.messages = res.data.error.data;
        return res.data.error.data;
    }, function errorCallback(res) {
        console.log("Hata", res);
        throw res;
    });
}
```

Then to delay the changing of the route until the `getMessages` data returns from the server, chain from the `getMessages` promise:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5169/api/Kullanicilar/KullaniciDogrula',
    data: loginMember
}).
  then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("message sent", response);
    $scope.data = response.data.error.data;
    if ($scope.data !== true) { throw "user error" };
    //username and password is correct
    console.log("User exists");
    return userTaskList.showActiveTasks(userName);
}).
  then(function (activeTaskResponse) {
    var activeTasks = activeTaskResponse;
    console.log("Active tasks (controller): ", activeTaskResponse);
    return userTaskList.showFinishedTasks(userName)
}).
  then(function (finishedTaskResponse) {
    var finishedTasks = finishedTaskResponse;
    console.log("Finished tasks(controller): ", finishedTaskResponse);
    //CHAIN from getMessages promise
    return $scope.getMessages();
}).
  then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //SAVE data before changing route
    panelService.set(data);
    $location.path( "/userPanel" );
    //OR STORE data before changing app
    //localStorage.setItem('panelData', JSON.stringify(data));             
    //$window.location.href = '../Kullanici/userPanel.html';
}).
  catch(function (response) {
    console.log("Couldn't send", response);
    throw response;
});
```

Comment: Sadly I still can't use or even see the values returned. I can post some links to screenshot of the console and full code here if its allowed.

Comment: I just came up with an idea. Would using AngularJS cookies or rootscope help? I'm not sure since I'm pretty newbie and never tried those.

Comment: Which router are you using? NgRoute or ui-router? Unless you are using a router, you will loose $rootScope and all service data.

Comment: Oh I injected `ngRoute` to my AngularJS module but haven't use it yet.

Comment: Sorry my english is not good. What do you mean by "moving target" ?

Comment: Related [AngularJS - Script stops running at factory function with promise return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313285/angularjs-script-stops-running-at-factory-function-with-promise-return).

Comment: yeah but I already mentioned that my problem starts when I redirect to another page. So this doesnt help me much.

Comment: I marked it as related because the code seems copied. Are [Snxby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008566/snxby) and [onur-cevik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7840796/onur-cevik) different accounts that you use? Or are you two in the same class doing homework together?  What is going on here?

Comment: its my main account. Since I was newbie and didn't know how to ask question got down voted pretty quickly. So I couldn't ask questions on that account anymore. This is why I opened this account. Its ok for me if moderators merge this account to that one  . Since I want to stay active in this site. Also this problem occured after that one so they are not the same question.